# Use c++ on raspberryPi3

Tags: pi-3, c++

Is there a way of using c++ on the raspberry pi without having to use the terminal and the compiler directly? I would like to know if there is an IDE avaiable like Visual Studio,eclipse etc... I'm using raspberrypi3 with the latest version of raspbian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use an IDE.  I write my C++ code using a text editor [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/) and that works very well for me.  With that said, however, I've used some IDEs recently, and I'll present a few alternatives and some thoughts on each.

### Eclipse

Yes, you can run Eclipse with CDT to develop C++ code on a Raspberry Pi.  However, I find the C++ support and Eclipse general slowness (especially on a Raspberry Pi Zero!) to be an impediment to productivity.  Unlike the other packages mentioned below, to my knowledge it still does not have any integration with the gdb debugger (or more GUI-friendly debuggers such as DDD).  This can be installed with `sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt`.

### NetBeans

Someone once suggested to me that NetBeans could be used for C++ programming.  I had thought it was only for Java, but apparently the C++ support exists and is pretty decent at this point.  See https://netbeans.org/downloads/ and choose the "OS Independent" version.  A popular alternative is to run NetBeans on a Windows machine and cross-compile.  I haven't done this, but many have.

### Code::Blocks

Code::Blocks is another popular IDE is available for the Pi.  `sudo apt-get install codeblocks` will install it.  See http://www.codeblocks.org/  for description and features.