# What visual programming language IDEs are available for the Pi?

Tags: python, ide

What visual programming language IDEs are available for programming Python on the Raspberry Pi? Especially for newbie.

Comment: I'm not a user of that kind of thing, but my gut tells me they are going to be resource intensive and hence not well suited to a modest, >= 1 GB RAM device.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: TBH, you can obviously write something close to a grammatically correct sentence (which is more than a lot of people online...) -- I think you should just find a decent editor or lightweight IDE (this is actually a blurry distinction, if we consider *autocompletion* and syntax checking more critical than being able to compose/compile/run within one application, the latter I think being mostly pointless with python) and jump in.

Comment: Looking around [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) is probably a decent choice.  You don't have to download it from there if you are using Raspbian `sudo apt install geany`.

Comment: This [page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments) may give you some other alternatives and things to try,  but I would agree with @goldilocks they will likely offer a far from optimal user experience and that Geany may be the best compromise between features and usability.

Comment: Thanks. Since i'm total newbie, more important is easy programming than anything else. @goldilocks do you mean that this IDE is run in Raspberry with 1 GB RAM? I meant that IDE runs in Desktop computer.

Comment: Another option would be natural language programming languages.

Comment: If you mean you want to write python using whatever method on your desktop, that's really off-topic here; it's the same language everywhere.  If you want to work remotely from the desktop with the pi using an IDE, see: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/36398/5538

Comment: Pretty sure [NLP stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_programming) will just lead you down a garden path until you are lost in the woods.  This is currently more of a concept than a pragmatic reality.  Put another way: Learning to program that way *isn't* going to be easier, and will leave you with your hands tied in various ways (i.e., you won't get far with it).  That said, [Wolfram Alpha](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RaspberryPi.html) is available.

Comment: I use [intelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) when I need to code Perl, and [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) for coding in Python. Mind you, I do most of my development on other systems and then just pull the new code to the Pi, but PyCharm does work just dandy on the Pi.

Answer (score 3):

[Thonny](http://proyectojuanchacon.blogspot.com.ee/2016/01/thonny-python-ide-for-beginners.html) and [Eric](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/201307261700129/Eric.html) are two decent Python IDEs that are small and lightweight.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the standard Python IDE comes with Raspbain by default which is decent especially for a newbie.

Otherwise, you could try [Ninja IDE](http://ninja-ide.org/). Install it by opening a terminal window and running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ninja-ide
```

Answer (score 3):

A popular IDE is Geany which is fairly small and lightweight. Its supports Python as well as C, Java, PHP and HTML. It only requires the GTK2 runtime libraries to be installed.

You can install it from the terminal by running:

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

Syntax highlighting, code folding, symbol name auto-completion, completion and snippets, call tips, code navigation, simple project management are all supported. I think you would be hard pressed to find a better alternative that is easier to install and works across as many different OS's and programming languages.

The official page can be found [here](http://www.geany.org/Main/HomePage).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of a complete set of answers...

You can use Visual Studio on a PC to write Python programs for a Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 IoT.