# Use Raspberry and Arduino IDE to program ESP8266 remotely

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I currently use Arduino IDE to generate binaries for ESP8266. Afterwards I copy the binaries with SFTP to my Raspberry Pi and flash the binaries using esptool.py.

These are lots of steps I need to do manually. Is it possible to automate this and use the Raspberry Pi as a programmer known to the Arduino IDE?

The goal is, that the "Upload" button in Arduino IDE does the full job.

Comment: I think the closest you will get is running the IDE on the Pi, which is probably not an improvement over your current method (particularly if it is headless).  WRT sftp, it is pretty clunky, people who code remotely would more commonly using sshfs (or NFS, or something along these lines): http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/36398/5538 This makes everything more transparent, although you would still have to run `esptool.py` on the Pi.

Comment: With an FTDI buddy or the like and a simple breadboard circuit you can program direct from the arduino.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I don't see an Arduino in this photograph ;)  The IDE can be used with the ESP8266 directly, which is what the OP is presumably doing.  It just uses a different back end.

Comment: @goldilocks Arduino as in the IDE the FTDI buddy acts as the programmer to the esp8266

Comment: Would the OTA update code for the ESP8266 do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Oak which has the esp8266 at the heart of it. Arduino can program direct via particle and also there is the particle online ide to program direct to the Oak.